# Reply to Inputted Email Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a contact form in my website and Its working but in my email setup, I'm using a static email and wish to use the email that was typed in the email field instead.

The data grabbed from the form looks like this

```
{'from_email': 'example@gmail.com', 'subject': 'Hello World', 'message': 'asdasdasd'}
```

My imports in my view.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
```

The class view looks like this

```
class ContactMe(View):
    template = "contact.html"
    context = {
        'form': ContactForm()
    }

    def get(self, request):
        print("getting form")
        return render(request, self.template, self.context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        def __init__(self):
            self.mailSender = mailSender()
            Mail = POST
            Mail.MailSender.send_mail()
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            print(data)
            send_mail(data['subject'], data['message'],
                      settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, data['from_email'])
     next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)`
```

the data['from_email'] was set to my email ['example@gmail.com'] and I changed it to the label name in the data that it gets ('from_email')

It works 100% with a static email instead of the variable form_email but using form_email gives an error

TypeError: "to" argument must be a list or tuple

I then changed it to

```
to=['from_email']
```

but then I got this error TypeError: send_mail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'to'

Reason for this is I want the person's email to be with the subject and message to my email so that I can directly reply from my inbox

Any Ideas?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Create a `EmailMessage` or `EmailMultiAlternatives` and set the `reply_to` parameter instead of the `from` parameter. Then `.send()` it (so don't use `send_mail`). You **cannot** fake the from address of an email, most SMTP providers won't allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** fake the "from" address of an email by trying to set it to `data['from_email']`, that's not allowed by most SMTP providers (they'll replace it back with the real "from"). But you **can** set the "reply-to" address (which will show up in your email client and allow to rapidly reply to the correct address).

To do that, instead of using `send_mail()`, create a `EmailMessage` or `EmailMultiAlternatives`, set the `reply_to` address and `send()` it:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    data['subject'], 
    data['message'], 
    to=["support@example.com"],  # where you receive the contact emails  
    from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    reply_to=[data['from_email']])
message.send()
```

Comment: I did not fake the email I just typed example@gmail.com here and not my actual email address did not want it to be in the post.

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you try to set the "from" address to anything else than the `settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` (which is the **real** email address you're sending the email from), you're _faking_ the from address. You want it to be the email address of the person that filled in the contact form (`data['from_email']`), which by definition is not _your email address_. That cannot be done.

Comment: Sorry Misread your response, I Have removed the send_mail() replaced it with EmailMessage section and I am still getting issues with this.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: got an unexpected keyword argument 'to'

Comment: if you remove the to just for testing purposes it complains about reply_to

Comment: Where are you importing `EmailMultiAlternatives` from? The error you're getting is not possible with the code I show above, look at the [`__init__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L400), it has `to` and `reply_to`.

Comment: I got it to work! I removed the import and saved and inserted the import again. It then picked up the to= and the reply_to= but it then complained that reply_to is not a tuple, I added extra [] around the argument like so  reply_to=[data['from_email']] and now its working!

Comment: that's right, to and reply_to need to be lists or tuples, fixed that now.

Comment: you probably want to use the settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL instead of settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER.

There are scenarios where it might be different (Sendgrid for example). I took the liberty to edit your answer.